# Setting NSImage from a file on the file system

Tags: swift

How can I set NSImage in a Swift macOS application by giving it a path to a path on the file system?

For example I have an image in a directory on my Mac and I want to turn it into a NSImage.

This is what I am doing:

```
let str = "/Users/jin/Desktop/Images/tree.jpg" 

if let imageRef = NSImage(byReferencingFile: str) {
    print("image size \(imageRef.size.width):\(imageRef.size.height)")
    self.sliderImage.image = imageRef
    print(str)
}
else {
    print("Image not found")
    print(str)
}
```

However, it produces an image with width and height of `0, 0`

Comment: You aren't supposed to do that in iOS and macOS.

Comment: Is there any reason?

Comment: You are not supposed to open a file other than one that the user has selected at their own will.

Comment: User will browse for file and select the image. After that image should display in application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
init(byReferencingFile:)
```

initializer of

```
NSImage
```

where you can specify a full or relative path to the file on your file system:

```
filename
A full or relative path name specifying the file with the desired image data. Relative paths must be relative to the current working directory.
```

You could also validate the existence of the file; also use a fileUrl instead:

```
guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: str) else {
    return
}

let fileUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: str)
```

Alternatively loading and examining it through NSData:

```
guard let imageData = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: str) else {
    return
}

guard let image = NSImage.init(data: imageData as Data) else {
    return
}
```

[NSImage init(byReferencingFile:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519955-init)

Comment: let str = "/Users/jin/Desktop/Images/tree.jpg"

        
        //let url = NSURL(string: str)

        
        if let imageRef = NSImage(byReferencingFile: str) {

            print("image size \(imageRef.size.width):\(imageRef.size.height)")

            self.sliderImage.image = imageRef

            print(str)


        } else {

            print("Image not found")


            print(str)


        }


This is what I am doing. It prints image with and height 0, 0

Comment: I moved you code to the question and updated my answer.

Comment: Image path is valid but height and width are zero.

Comment: did you try printing the size AFTER actually displaying the image on your screen? The reference says: "This method initializes the image object lazily. It does not actually open the specified file or create any image representations from its data until an app attempts to draw the image or request information about it."

Comment: I did, still width and height are zero.

Comment: next I would try a different image, different location on the file system and then loading it from the application's bundle as well.

Comment: I've tried different images different location.
I tried adding image in asset folder and then sliderImage.image = NSImage(named: "tree") and it worked. But that is not the requirement of project.

Comment: try getting it into NSData first, then examine the data, then turn the data into NSImage.

Comment: It was path problem. I found it accidentally when I was try to add browse button for user to select folder containing images.
I tried printing the path and it was the same as defined as String. Don't why but it's working. Thank you so much for helping me.